# MVC 5 not parsing JSON object array into .NET object array, why?

Tags: ajax, arrays, asp.net-mvc, json, json-deserialization

I have an action that accepts an object like:

```
 public class OrderSubmissionViewModel
    {
        /* Some properties trimmed for brevity */

        public OrderSubmissionProductViewModel[] Products { get; set; }
    }
```

And the bottom property, the OrderSubmissionProductViewModel array looks like:

```
    public class OrderSubmissionProductViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
        public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    }
```

The Javascript (knockout) view model looks like:

```
var OrderSubmissionViewModel = function (viewModel) {
    var self = this;

    /* Omitted Properties that parse fine */

    self.Products = $.map(viewModel.productList(), function (v, i) {
        return {
            Id: v.Id,
            Price: v.Price(),
            Qty: v.Qty(),
            Tax: v.Tax()
        }
    });
}
```

I have an Action with this signature:

```
public ActionResult SubmitOrder(OrderSubmissionViewModel submission)
```

Used by the following Javascript function:

```
self.submitOrder = function () {
    var submission = new OrderSubmissionViewModel(self);

$.ajax({
    url: self.urlSubmitOrder,
    data: JSON.stringify({ submission: submission }),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () { alert("Submitted"); },
    fail: function () { alert("Failed"); }
});
}
```

For some reason, any form of object array from my view via ajax is not parsed correctly, and my Products property comes up empty or null. The other properties, such as ints and strings, are parsed fine.

The submission object has JSON.stringify, and looks like this in Fiddler (with some other properties trimmed for brevity):

```
{"submission":{"Products":[{"Id":8888,"Price":16,"Qty":1,"Tax":1.48},{"Id":8787,"Price":8.99,"Qty":1,"Tax":0.83}]}}
```

If I put JSON.stringify on the inner array, it looks like:

```
{"submission":{"Products":"[{\"Id\":8888,\"Price\":16,\"Qty\":1,\"Tax\":1.48},{\"Id\":8787,\"Price\":8.99,\"Qty\":1,\"Tax\":0.83}]"}}
```

The controller will not parse either one! Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: can you include the javascript code you're using to call the server?

Comment: what is submission for You do not have submission in your  OrderSubmissionViewModel

Comment: @COLDTOLD: Yes, but the other properties I omitted here (just ints, strings, etc.) _do_ get parsed correctly. Only the Products array fails to parse.

Comment: @chavakane: Added the JS viewmodel and ajax call to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON has a top level property called "Submission" that your .NET Object does not. That is going to keep it from parsing into the object correctly, though I cannot say with 100% certainty that that is the reason why.

based on your edit, here is my edit:

```
self.submitOrder = function () {
    var submission = new OrderSubmissionViewModel(self);

$.ajax({
    url: self.urlSubmitOrder,
    data: JSON.stringify({ submission }),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () { alert("Submitted"); },
    fail: function () { alert("Failed"); }
});
}
```

Comment: It parses the other properties inside the "submission" object fine. I omitted the other properties in my question. The Products array is the only one that it has trouble with.

Comment: But your C# object doesn't have a Submission property. Just a products property. If you look at your JSON, you go Submission -> Products ->ItemsArray of Products. Just remove the "Submission" part. See the code I posted in my edit.

Comment: @Goblyn27: the C# object doesn't have "submission", but the action *does*. The model binder will understand that to be the value passed for the `submission` parameter and unpack the rest of the object into that. This is not the problem.

Comment: Indeed this was what worked. I didn't think it would make a difference since my other top level properties deserialized correctly. I've always been using JSON objects for the data in my ajax objects, so that's why I've had trouble with this for so long. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON has a property "submission" that is not in your C# object, so it cannot be parsed. Products needs to be on the top level of your JSON object, like so:

```
{"Products":"[{\"Id\":8888,\"Price\":16,\"Qty\":1,\"Tax\":1.48},
{\"Id\":8787,\"Price\":8.99,\"Qty\":1,\"Tax\":0.83}]"}
```

Then the JSON structure matches the C# structure and it should be fine (unless you also have some other problem)